Allowing File/Folder modeler input as input for a QgsProcessing algorithm
I have a simple QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
    QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination,
)


class TestAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    def createInstance(self):
        return TestAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return "test"

    def displayName(self):
        return "Test"

    def group(self):
        return "Example scripts"

    def groupId(self):
        return "examplescripts"

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(
                "FILE_PATH", "File path",
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        file_path = self.parameterAsFileOutput(parameters, "FILE_PATH", context)
        ...
        return {"FILE_PATH": file_path}

I want to use a File/Folder model input as input for the file path but if I select Model Input, the list of inputs is empty.

How can I make my algorithm support the File/Folder Model Input?
